# github: where can I see the version number?

Tags: github

is there no specific position/place on Github where I can see the version number of the latest build of a project, eg https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel ?

Thanks!
mtemp

Answer (score 1):

You can see in `Releases` section:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/releases

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. it says latest commit with the version number right next to it.

[image]